# Check if a variable is between two numbers with Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a problem with this code:

```
if (90 >>= angle =<< 180)
```

The error explanation is:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

I understand what this means but how do I turn the above code into correct code?

Comment: You should update your question and explain what your are trying to do or test for. `if (90 >>= angle =<< 180 )` does not make sense, and its not clear to me you're doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: Added the [tag:java] tag, based on the assumption that you're writing Java code. Feel free to correct this if it's wrong.

Comment: @Dukeling why do you think this is java and not c, c++, c#, javascript?

Comment: @MiserableVariable Pre-edit mentioned Android (which I removed in the spirit of brevity). To my knowledge, Android dev is primarily Java. And that's a Java IDE / compiler error (although I'm certainly not saying it can't be an error in another language as well, thus the comment).

Comment: Thanks for the comments i have just started writing code with Eclipse/java and this was my first post. many thanks for all the comments

Comment: If this really is java code, `>>=` is not a comparison operator. It is the bit-shift assign operator.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I see some errors in your code.
Your probably meant the mathematical term

90 <= angle <= 180, meaning angle in range 90-180.

```
if (angle >= 90 && angle <= 180) {

// do action
}
```

Comment: Can't we do if(90<=angle<=180) ??

Comment: No.  First, that's not equivalent: note the order of the comparisons. Second, Java has no ternary "<=" operator. It takes two arguments and returns a boolean. Since all operators besides assignment are evaluated left-to-right, this would associate as `(90 <= angle) <= 180`, which is comparing a boolean to an integer, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

```
//If "x" is between "a" and "b";

.....

int m = (a+b)/2;

if(Math.abs(x-m) <= (Math.abs(a-m)))

{
(operations)
}
```

......

//have to use floating point conversions if the summ is not even;

Simple example :

```
//if x is between 10 and 20

if(Math.abs(x-15)<=5)
```

Comment: Sorry for commenting on an old post, but this is the correct answer i'm looking for, since in my case I don't know in advance the value of a and b..

Comment: While mathematically elegant (at least if viewed with a specific frame of mind), it has a lot of problems: code intention isn't clear to all readers, any bugs will not stand out, more operations in the source, more operations in the bytecode, floating-point overflow will cause wrong answers if they happen.

Answer (score 5):

You can use apache Range API.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html

Comment: link only answers are discouraged, please include the relevant information in your answer. Read [answer] for more information

Answer (score 5):

```
public static boolean between(int variable, int minValueInclusive, int maxValueInclusive) {
    return variable >= minValueInclusive && variable <= maxValueInclusive;
}
```

[A Java method to determine if an integer is between a range](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-method-integer-is-between-a-range)

Comment: Why not just do `return i >= minValueInclusive && i <= maxValueInclusive`?

Comment: Absolutely. But your syntax is for advanced developers.

Comment: Hardly. There’s no point manually returning booleans right after checking them, and it’s a lot simpler (at least to me)

Answer (score 3):

`<<=` is like `+=`, but for a left shift. `x <<= 1` means `x = x << 1`.  That's why `90 >>= angle` doesn't parse. And, like others have said, Java doesn't have an elegant syntax for checking if a number is an an interval, so you have to do it the long way. It also can't do `if (x == 0 || 1)`, and you're stuck writing it out the long way.

Answer (score 2):

are you writing java code for android?
in that case you should write maybe

```
if (90 >= angle && angle <= 180) {
```

updating the code to a nicer style (like some suggested) you would get:

```
if (angle <= 90 && angle <= 180) {
```

now you see that the second check is unnecessary or maybe you mixed up `<` and `>` signs in the first check and wanted actually to have

```
if (angle >= 90 && angle <= 180) {
```

Comment: I removed the downvote, it has some style that is closer to the typical math term 90 <= angle <= 180; (And it is indepenedent whether for android or not)

Comment: If angle is less or equal to 90, wouldn't it also be less than or equal to 180?  Am I missing something?

Comment: yes it would be, that's a probable bug in the original code as well, many already pointed it out - i'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think using [org.apache.commons.lang3.Range](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html) is a nice solution for this. It can also integrate nicely with Guava Preconditions for argument checking. Some example code showing usage is

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.Range;

import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a range object
        Range<Double> validRange = Range.between(90.0, 180.0);
        // and some test values
        List<Double> testValues = List.of(65.3, 89.99, 90.0, 90.11, 134.4, 177.7, 180.00, 180.000001, 32321.884);
        // Test them all
        for (Double testValue : testValues) {
            // Check if it's in the range
            final boolean inRange = validRange.contains(testValue);
            System.out.println(String.format("[%f] in range [%b]", testValue, inRange));
        }
    }
}
```

it prints

```
[65.300000] in range [false]
[89.990000] in range [false]
[90.000000] in range [true]
[90.110000] in range [true]
[134.400000] in range [true]
[177.700000] in range [true]
[180.000000] in range [true]
[180.000001] in range [false]
[32321.884000] in range [false]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are programming in Java, this works:

```
if (90 >= angle  &&  angle <= 180 )  {
```

(don't you mean 90 is *less* than `angle`? If so: `90 <= angle`)

Comment: that is a matter of style, but I know many people who were coding C/C++ and are writing the value always left, so that the compiler complains if they forgot and `=` ... `if (9 = x)` - compiler error - `if (x = 9)` - always valid (in C)

Comment: @zahorak if (9 == x) this is ugly c style, not neccerarry in java, because if (9 = x) is not possible. such a notation is only used for "string".equals(otherString);

Comment: I see your alternative. Style is subjective. Your style is different. I'm not downvoting you for it.

Comment: I meant angle must be 90 or bigger and lower then 180 degrees i solved it with : if (angle >= 90 && angle < 180) {

Comment: I tried to remove the downvote (does not work, needs an edit), because it has some style that is closer to the typical math term 90 <= angle <= 180;  However for a code like if (90 > alpha) I still would downvote. And Style is not onyl subjective (See Checkstyle and Code formatting rules) However the your code is valid to checkstyle

Comment: Edited. Agreed about `90 >= angle` needing to be reversed, but it seems pretty obvious, as I mentioned in my answer, that the OP means between 90 and 180, which is why I left it that way. Thanks for the un-downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a static method can be a benefit in terms of readability and if such a static method could be defined as a standard, there could be also improvements in terms of performance:
let me say, imagine that in `java.lang.Math` you have a method `isBetween(int toCheck, int from, int to)`, which is defined as

```java
public static boolean isBetween(int toCheck, int from, int to){
  // eventually validate the range
  return from <= toCheck && toCheck <= to;
}
```

the first benefit can be that, if you `import static Math.isBetween`, than tou can write code like

```java
if(isBetween(userInput, 0, 16)){
  //...
}
```

and the second benefit would be that, hitting this method many times (for boundary checks, for example, in Strings, arrays, or other statically-sized  data structures), can lead to an easily C2-compiled method (probably inlined), and eventually if someone points out that the HotSpot compiler generates a branch, due to the fact that there is a conditionated jump, then can write an improvement that generates brachless code, and every application of this method can benefit, just upgrading to a newer runtime.

Another improvement in readability could come from project Valhalla: if `int`s can have methods, than you could just write `if(userInput.isBetween(0, 16))`

Answer (score -1):

```
if (age >= 90 && age <=180) {
    // statements
}
```

This checks is a number is between, you can also use a built in function called Range or any other built function that can be of use like range between