# How to compare three BigDecimal values

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I need to compare three Bigdecimal values like this.
Eg:

```
    if(Min<=Value<=Max){
     //Do this
    }else{
     //Do this
    }
```

All three values are BigDecimals.How to compare like this in Java.
Thanks.
Anuradha.

Comment: Adapt [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761875/check-if-a-variable-is-between-two-numbers-with-java) with `compareTo`.

Comment: `Java` doesn't support comparisons like how `Python` does `(a < b < c)`. You will need to use two comparisons in the `if case`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `compareTo`. 
The example you provide would be:

```
if(Min.compareTo(Value)<=0 && Max.compareTo(Value) >=0){
     //Do this
    }else{
     //Do this
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is that you have to split the comparison up into two separate checks, e.g.:

```
if ( Min <= Value && Value <= Max ) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

However, since you're using `BigDecimal`, these comparators (`<`, `<=`, etc.) won't work, so you'll have to make use of [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29):

```
if ( (Min.compareTo(Value) <= 0) && (Value.compareTo(Max) <= 0) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```